# Angular SSR and I18nModule Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\browser\assets\i18n\en.json'

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I'm trying to configure my Angular app to user Server Side Rendering with @ngx-translate.
I'm following [this tutorial](https://indepth.dev/implementing-multi-language-angular-applications-rendered-on-server/#solution-2-provide-everything-in-a-single-module) using Solution 2

When I run the app using `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` and then access localhost I get the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\browser\assets\i18n\en.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
    at readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
    at TranslateFSLoader../src/app/i18n/translate-loaders.ts.TranslateFSLoader.getTranslation (C:\Users\Aramis\Documents\Projects\Rainbow\frontend\src\main\frontend\dist\server.js:178773:86)
    at TranslateService.getTranslation (C:\Users\Aramis\Documents\Projects\Rainbow\frontend\src\main\frontend\dist\server.js:243494:54)
    at TranslateService.retrieveTranslations (C:\Users\Aramis\Documents\Projects\Rainbow\frontend\src\main\frontend\dist\server.js:243469:87)
    at TranslateService.use (C:\Users\Aramis\Documents\Projects\Rainbow\frontend\src\main\frontend\dist\server.js:243434:28)
    at new I18nModule (C:\Users\Aramis\Documents\Projects\Rainbow\frontend\src\main\frontend\dist\server.js:178717:19)
    at _createClass (C:\Users\Aramis\Documents\Projects\Rainbow\frontend\src\main\frontend\dist\server.js:24268:20)
    at _createProviderInstance (C:\Users\Aramis\Documents\Projects\Rainbow\frontend\src\main\frontend\dist\server.js:24230:26)
    at initNgModule (C:\Users\Aramis\Documents\Projects\Rainbow\frontend\src\main\frontend\dist\server.js:24163:32)
```

I have no idea what is happening.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "rainbow-pet",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --aot --prod --build-optimizer",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run rainbow-pet:server:production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.22",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "0.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ng-http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^6.0.1",
    "ngx-translate-cache": "^9.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false
  }
}
```

server.js

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
// Express Engine
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';
//import 'localstorage-polyfill';
import * as proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

//import { readFileSync } from "fs";
// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');


// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');

//global['localStorage'] = localStorage;

app.use(cookieParser());

const apiProxy = proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:8080' });
app.use('/api', apiProxy);

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

You can see here that I'm using  **http-proxy-middleware** to proxy 'api/' to localhost:8080

i18n.module.ts and translate-loader.ts are exactly the same as the tutorial. Also the folder structure.

[Here](https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/ssr-with-i18n/tree/step-4) is the git code of solution 2

Thanks

Comment: Manually copy the missing file first to see if it works. Is that file in your source assets? The link to your git repo is invalid btw.

Comment: @David oops, sorry about that.  And yes, the file is in my source assets